# When function invoked with dynamic data it prints results in a new window

Tags: javascript, redirect

Some problems with javascript. There is function createPagination(index, n_pages). It creates paginations. If you invoke function in debug mode in this way createPaginatio(2,5), i.e. providing static values, then pagination is created in the same main window. But if you invoke it with dynamic values which are retrieved from somewhere else, then paginations are created in a new window. And this is wrong, I want to see it in the same main window.
This is code:

```
 function createPagination (index, n_pages) {
alert(index+" "+n_pages)
var n_links = 5;
var n_index = index;


document.write('<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="right"><tr>');


if (n_index != 0){ // if not a first page
document.write(' <td><a href="javascript:setMessaget('+0+')" ><img src="js/images/button_page_first.gif" alt="First page" width="20" height="20" border="0"></a> <a href="javascript:setMessaget('+(n_index - 1)+')" ><img src="js/images/button_page_prev.gif" alt="Previous page" width="20" height="20" border="0" ></a></td>');
}
document.write('<td>Page ' + n_index + ' of ' + n_pages + '.</td>');
if (n_links) {

if (n_links > n_pages)
n_links = n_pages;
document.write('<td>Page: ');
var n_sideLinks = Math.floor((n_links - 1) / 2),
 n_firstLink, n_lastLink;

if (n_index + n_sideLinks >= n_pages) {
n_firstLink = n_pages - n_links + 1;
n_lastLink = n_pages;
}

else if (n_index - n_sideLinks <= 0) {
n_firstLink = 1;
n_lastLink = n_links;
}

else {
n_firstLink = n_index - n_sideLinks;
n_lastLink = n_firstLink + n_links - 1;
}

for (var i = n_firstLink; i <= n_lastLink; i++){
document.write(i == n_index ? i + ' ' : '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="setMessaget('+i+')">' + i + '</a> ');
} // for loop
document.write('</td>');

}

if (n_index != n_pages){
document.write('<td><a href="javascript:setMessaget('+(n_index + 1)+')" ><img src="js/images/button_page_next.gif" alt="Next page" width="20" height="20" border="0" /></a> <a href="javascript:setMessaget('+n_pages+')" > <img src="js/images/button_page_last.gif" alt="Last page" width="20" height="20" border="0" /></a></td>');
}

document.write(' </tr></table>');

}
```

I tried to solve the problem by inputting into document.write()
Code:
Code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)")> </a>
```

, but it does not help.

As well I tried this:
Code:

Code:

```
stopDef = function(e) {
if (e && e.preventDefault)
  e.preventDefault();
else if (window.event && window.event.returnValue)
  window.eventReturnValue = false;
};
```

I invoked this function in this way: stopDef() I am not sure what value I need to pass.
What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell because we don't know how are you retrieving the values and what do you mean by new window, but it may have something to do with a fact that calling `document.write` upon a page which is already loaded overwrites the page content.

Comment: New window: the web site consists so far of one page and javascript code is in that page. When you run program the page is created, all data appears on the page, from the code given above I see this alert pop up alert(index+" "+n_pages)
and then when the button on alert is pressed I see a new white window and created pagination inside the window.

Answer (score 0):

```
 I am retrieving values in this way:                                                                          

function setMessage(index, location, category, session)
        {
                var xmlHttp = getXmlHttpRequest();
                     //alert(index)
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
                    {                     
                        if(xmlHttp.responseText.indexOf("<body>") != -1) {
                            pageNumber = xmlHttp.responseText.substring(xmlHttp.responseText.indexOf("<title>") + 7, xmlHttp.responseText.indexOf("</title>")) // gets the number of table being sent from <title> tag
                            s = xmlHttp.responseText.substring(xmlHttp.responseText.indexOf("<body>") + 6, xmlHttp.responseText.indexOf("</body>"))

                           document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=s;
                            getTableNumber(pageNumber) // gets the number of tables available for display
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
                        }                  
                    }                    
                 }

                    xmlHttp.open("GET","app/messages/" + index+"/"+location+"/"+category+"/"+session,true);
               xmlHttp.send(null);
            }
            // gets the number of tables (rows) being store in database for an individual user
              function getTableNumber(pageNumber){

                 var xmlHttp = getXmlHttpRequest();
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
                    {
                        if(xmlHttp.responseText.indexOf("<body>") != -1) {
                             s = xmlHttp.responseText.substring(xmlHttp.responseText.indexOf("<body>") + 6, xmlHttp.responseText.indexOf("</body>"))// retrieves number of tables stored in database

                       createPagination(pageNumber, s)// invokes function which creates paginations


                    }
                    }
                }
                xmlHttp.open("GET","app/messages/tableNumber/" +getCookie("eMartbyM"),true);
               xmlHttp.send(null);

             }
```

The last function invokes createPagination(index, n_pages) function.